# Get count of string obj in list by substring

Tags: python

I have a Python list like this:

```
date_list = ['2016-01-11','2016-02-05','2016-02-24','2016-03-15','2016-03-12']
```

and I would like to get the count of the objects that contains a specific substring (for example `2016-02-`).

Actually I have something, but unfortunately it works only with string matches.

```
print (dates1.count("2016-01-")) # doesn't work
print (dates1.count("2016-01-11")) # works
```

I could do it in two steps by looping through `date_list`, removing the last 2 chars, but it would be great to use a more elegant solution, so I would really appreciate if somebody could show a smarter way if it's possible.

My goal is to get something like this:

```
2016-01  1
2016-02  2
2016-03  2
```

Comment: @Kasramvd Sorry, I don't need that. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension within `collections.Counter`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter([d.rsplit('-',1)[0] for d in date_list])
Counter({'2016-03': 2, '2016-02': 2, '2016-01': 1})
```